# Webpack extract text plugin not generating a separate CSS file?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack-3, extracttextwebpackplugin

I have one **src/styles/main.scss** file which I want to convert to **build/styles/main.css** and then use it in **index.html**.

I have been trying to setup webpack with [text extractor plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) but unable to achieve the final result.

This is my directory structure:

```
project
 // build needs to be generated, as of now only js folder with index.js is generated
 - build
 - src
   - styles
     - main.scss
     - components
       - header.scss
   - js
     - stores
     // some other files
 - webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/js');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

const config = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    "index": APP_DIR + '/js/index.jsx'
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader', // backup loader when not building .css file
          'css-loader!sass-loader'
        )
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("build/styles/main.css")
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Try to use `loader:` instead of the webpack 2 attribute `use:`

Comment: @IvanMinakov still no result, it doesn't give out any **main.css** file.

Comment: Ok, are you sure, that your  [name].scss imported to your entry js file?

Comment: No its not imported, if I try to do that I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0) for @import` in main.scss.

Comment: `require('main.scss');` in your entry js file

Comment: Thanks @IvanMinakov `require(main.scss)` worked for me.